# Are there downsides with docstrings in R?

Tags: r, ess

I do not like the automatic indentation of comments in 
ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics) mode, because it is so far to the right.

```
normalize <- function(values){
                                        # comment
  return(2* values / (max(values) - min(values)) )
}
```

Python uses also docstrings for comments. And I play around with it in R.

```
normalize <- function(values){
  "comment
   line 2 of comment"
  return(2* values / (max(values) - min(values)) )
}
```

I am sure I could fix the ESS indentation of comments too, but I like the idea of **multiline
comments**. Are there any downsides with docstrings in GNU R?

Comment: FWIW: two comment characters in ESS `##` will indent to the "correct" level of indentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments that begin with `##` instead of `#` will be auto-indented in line with the current level of indentation.

```
j <- function(x) {
                                        # One hash auto-indents to column 40 
    ## Two hashes auto-indent to current level
### Three hashes auto-indent to BOL
    rnorm(x)
}
```

Comment: They will be indented but they'll be in line with the current level of indentation.

Comment: @Jonas -- Three downsides I can think of right off the bat. (1) `#` stands out better: when using `"` there's no easy marker on each line telling you whether or not it's a comment. (2) Comments that begin with `#` in a package's source code are not visible to end users in the body of the function. Annotations describing implementation details can appear in one place without cluttering up the other. (3) Comments beginning with `#` can include quoted strings.